# Naming remote proxy classes

Tags: design-patterns, proxy

What are some good names for the client and server side classes that communicate over the network when implementing a remote proxy? The classes are often called stub and skelleton but I don't find those names very "intention revealing". Are there any other (better) alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The conventions in CORBA are "stub" and "servant" but I agree the names aren't great.  I like "proxy" instead of stub and I guess "servant" isn't too bad.

Comment: I like using the suffix "Proxy".